# Why won't this insert into my database?

Tags: java, php, android, mysql

I am building and android app and want to submit this data into my online database. It executes the `onPostExecute` method so I know that it is getting called

However, when I look for the entry in my DB, it's not there.  Why is this?

Any help at all would be greatly appreciated.

AsyncTask

```
private class SendTheYak extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>
{
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

    }

    /**
     * Creating product
     * */
    @Override

    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
        JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();


        String message = newYak.getText().toString();


          // Create a new HttpClient and Post Header
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://www.dichoapp.com/Chatter/sendMessage.php");

        try {
            // Building Parameters
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("userID", "William"));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("lat", "35.5"));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("long", "28.3"));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("distance", "2"));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("message", message));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("handle", "android"));


            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

            // Execute HTTP Post Request
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        }



        return null;
    }
    /**
     * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
     * **/
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "It sent to DB", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

}

php

```
<?php

    $DB_HostName = "localhost";
$DB_Name = "xxx";
$DB_User = "xxx";
$DB_Pass = "xxx";

$con = mysql_connect($DB_HostName,$DB_User,$DB_Pass) or die(mysql_error()); 
mysql_select_db($DB_Name,$con) or die(mysql_error()); 


$userID = $_POST["userID"];
$lat = $_POST["lat"];
$long = $_POST["long"];
$distance = $_POST["distance"];
$message = $_POST["message"];
$message = mysql_real_escape_string($message);
$handle = $_POST["hndl"];
$handle = mysql_real_escape_string($handle);
$hidePin = $_POST["hidePin"];

if(empty($hidePin)){
    $hidePin = "0";
}


if(empty($handle)){
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO xxx (User_ID, Latitude, Longitude, Distance, Message, HidePin) VALUES ('$userID', '$lat', '$long', '$distance', '$message', '$hidePin')", $con);
    $messageID = mysql_insert_id();

}else{
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO xxx (User_ID, Latitude, Longitude, Distance, Message, Handle, HidePin) VALUES ('$userID', '$lat', '$long', '$distance', '$message', '$handle', '$hidePin')", $con);
    $messageID = mysql_insert_id();
}
```

Comment: What error is received?

Comment: no error is received. nothing is just pushed into the database table

Comment: Can you modify your php script, to write a log in a txt file, storing the sql query??

Comment: dont know how to do that, can you give me a link as a reference?

Comment: I think you should be doing `method.equals("POST")` instead of `method == "POST"`

Comment: I dont think it is the php though, because this exact php works with the ios app

Comment: Where are you getting JSONParser from? I'm not finding it in the Android APIs for JSON.

Comment: my JSONParser acts just as a helper and it contains all of my parsing methods

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It wasn't working because I wasn't meeting my own foreign key constraint in the database with my hard-coded values. So I just changed it to real data and it worked like a champ.

Answer (score 0):

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO xxx (User_ID, Latitude, Longitude, Distance, Message, HidePin) VALUES ('$userID', '$lat', '$long', '$distance', '$message', '$hidePin')", $con);
```

Error in the mysql_query function.Actually it is `mysqli_query()` when you use it with connection variable.

alternatively 
if you use `mysql_query` don't use connection variable `$con`.

try

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO xxx (User_ID, Latitude, Longitude, Distance, Message, HidePin) VALUES ('$userID', '$lat', '$long', '$distance', '$message', '$hidePin')");
```

or

```
mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO xxx (User_ID, Latitude, Longitude, Distance, Message, HidePin) VALUES ('$userID', '$lat', '$long', '$distance', '$message', '$hidePin')");
```

Comment: are you sure thats the problem? Because that same code works when I use it with the ios app

Comment: If this is PHP/JSON connection mostly the error will occur in PHP file.I have encountered it many times while connecting with Android mobile.try mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO xxx (User_ID, Latitude, Longitude, Distance, Message, HidePin) VALUES ('$userID', '$lat', '$long', '$distance', '$message', '$hidePin')"); refer http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_query.asp.I have referred this link for your error.

Comment: @WillJamieson: are u developing for android or iphone.If possible send me the project.I can help u out.mail id:arun.naagarajan@gmail.com

Answer (score -1):

try this

use in activity

```
    nameValuePairs2 = new  ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
 nameValuePairs2.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username",username));
nameValuePairs2.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password",password));
     try{
             HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
             HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(mainurl+"registration.php");
             httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs2));
             HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
             String the_string_response = convertResponseToString(response);
         //    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Response " + the_string_response, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
         }catch(Exception e){
             //  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "ERROR " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            //   System.out.println("Error in http connection "+e.toString());
         }
```

and in php file

```
$sql="insert into login (username,password)values('".$_REQUEST['username']."','".$_REQUEST['password']."')";
 $r=mysql_query($sql);
 if(!$r)echo "Error in query: Record not submitted";
else echo "data submitted successfully";
 mysql_close();
```

Answer (score -2):

Where are you getting JSONParser from?  I'm not finding it in the [Android APIs for JSON](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/package-summary.html).  If you print out the JSON received from your request, I'd be guessing you're not actually making a legit call to start with.

Comment: This is not an answer, is it?